# Pattern matching in let binding in F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I wanna do:

```
let Some(x) = bar in ...
```

but I can't do this unless I do

```
let Some(x) as idontcare = bar in ...
```

is there a better way to say "I don't care about the whole pattern, just match the inside"

(I would use `_` but that doesn't parse so I am using `__` instead)

Yes I know this is partial, I just am doing a quick script.

Edit: Also this is just an example with a builtin sum type, so `Option.get` is not generic; plus I want this to be inline like the Haskell let-bindings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let Some(x) = bar
```

defines a new function `Some`, shadowing the existing constructor.  Instead, you want:

```
let (Some(x)) = bar
```

Comment: Cool. It's kind of bizarre you can shadow constructors in let-bindings at all, given the equivalent in ``match`` limbs is kosher

Comment: The warning can be suppressed by `#nowarn "25"`, but how do you get around the `MatchFailureException`? (_The match cases were incomplete_)

Comment: I don't; if the operation fails there are bigger issues and I just abort the program and clean up after it.

Comment: `let (Some x) = bar` -- to avoid an additional pair of parens.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `match`:

```
match bar with | Some(x) -> ...
```

if you're trying to match an option specifically you could use `Option.get`:

```
bar |> Option.get |> ...
```

Comment: This works, but only for Option and the ``match`` is a bit more verbose for inline stuff